# Addition not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript

Somebody please help me. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

I'm trying to add up some numbers.

Instead the adding the 2 numbers it is just placing the 2 numbers next to each other; as in:
3 + 3 = 33 (instead of 6) !!!

If I replace the + with a * then it returns the correct result (9)

What is happening?

```
<p id="A">3</p> 
<p id="B">3</p>

<p id="score"></p>

<script>

var AA = document.getElementById("A").innerHTML;
var BB = document.getElementById("B").innerHTML;

var result = AA + BB;

document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = result;

</script>
```

Comment: because they are strings, not numbers, you are doing string concatenation instead of addition

Comment: `+` is used for both addition and string concatenation. Which one do you think you are doing?

Comment: add more pluses: `result = +AA + +BB;` or use minus: `result = AA - -BB;`

Answer (score 4):

That's because they're strings so you're getting string concatenation. [Convert them to numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) before performing addition.

```
AA = parseInt(AA, 10);
BB = parseInt(BB, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are getting back from the html are strings, not numbers. You need to parse them as numbers first:

```
var AA = parseInt(document.getElementById("A").innerHTML, 10);
var BB = parseInt(document.getElementById("B").innerHTML, 10);
```

`parseInt` will convert the string to a number, and make your addition work correctly. The second parameter in the `parseInt` call is the radix, which will help prevent confusing mishaps when it comes to actually parsing the numbers

Comment: radix is important! That may confuse the conversion at times

Comment: Ah, good catch, I had added it